# Steam error missing libGL.so.1

Tags: steam

when downloading steam to my amd64 bit ubuntu pc i get the error-you are missing the following 32-bit libraries and steam may not run: libGL.so.1

any fixes would be much appreciated

Answer (score 8):

This solved it for me (I have an NVidia card):

```
sudo apt install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

From https://wiki.debian.org/Steam

Note that this will download 32-bit versions of legacy-drivers. If you are not using a legacy-nvidia-driver, running a

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-libs:i386`

instead of the above (described in https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#multiarch-install) is probably the better option (this will download 32-bit-versions of the non-legacy-drivers).

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that the package was in the /app-install/ library, so I used the Upgrade command, everything was installed and I was able to login.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade steam -f
```

Comment: This is the approach everyone should try out first!

Answer (score 4):

The reason why there are so many fixes suggested is because this error is saying that the library needed for Steam to process certain graphics is not present. And the specific of what is needed on a per-system basis could vary. Run steam from the command line to see what your system needs. You'll see an output like this:

```
Package xterm needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1:i386 needs to be installed
x-terminal-emulator: invalid option -- 'T'
QTerminal 0.14.1
Usage: qterminal [OPTION]...
```

Go ahead and install those packages:

`sudo apt-get install -y [package-name-1] [packagename2] [...]`

And then try running steam again. Should be good as new.

Answer (score 1):

If the above method does not work, please try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

Comment: I found that `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` before the above helped me.

Comment: For me, the package name was simply `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`. After doing the dpkg add-architecture thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

This will install packages to support 32-bit libraries on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what fixed it was:

```
sudo apt install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

And a reboot. I'm running Xenial 16.04 on on a Dell XPS 15 laptop, with an Nvidia GTX 1050 graphics chip. I suspect the solution that works will be quite hardware-specific.

Answer (score -2):

I tried installing steam with the file I downloaded from [their website](http://store.steampowered.com/) but got that error.
I uninstalled steam and then reinstalled it with the command `sudo apt-get install steam` and now it works fine.